# Share Navigation Drawer with multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I have a navigation drawer activity.
Behind most of the menu items i have various fragment and I only replace the content layout with the fragment like this:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_menu, new InformationFragment()).commit();
```

So when I click on a menu item, the navigation drawer slides back to the left, while the content changes to whatever is in the fragment and I can keep using the navigation drawer.

But one of the menu items does require its own Activity, so instead of a transaction to a new fragment I do:

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In this new activity I can add the same navigation drawer as I use in my first activity and this works, but I cant imagine that this is the best way to handle this situation.

Is it possible to have the navigation drawer "above" the activities so they can share it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented this on a project. My main inspiration for the implementation came from the [Google I/O official app](https://github.com/google/iosched).

To summarize the main points:

- Create an `AppNavigationView` that holds all the logic for displaying navigation items, closing or opening the drawer and handling click events
- Create a `BaseActivity` that has a an `AppNavigationView` member
- Make sure that each activity that requires a navigation drawer *extends* the `BaseActivity` you just created

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this